# How to format this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table **posts** with columns *board_id, author_id, message*. I have another table **users** with columns *id, name, avatar_url*.

I need to write a query to get all of the users that have posted on a given board, with no duplicates. The query should return the full user row (id, name, avatar_url).

I've tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.*, posts.author_id
FROM users
INNER JOIN posts
ON users.id = posts.author_id
WHERE posts.board_id = [desired board ID]
```

but that's giving me duplicates of each user.

There is also the possibility that my query is correct and I've goofed on something elsewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple query that will get you all the rows in users with post activity w/o duplication

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE id IN (SELECT author_id FROM posts WHERE board_id = [desired board]
```

You could also use your basic syntax with a distinct on everything you need distinct, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.*
FROM users
JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.author_id
WHERE posts.board_id = [desired board ID]
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, correct solution with the shortest query. It turned out my original example was fine, but I had introduced a typo when I was sending it to the DB and not caught it. Thanks for pointing out I don't need to select posts.author_id to run the join

Answer (score 0):

Just group by the user id, like so:

```
SELECT users.id, MIN(users.name), MIN(users.avatar_url)
FROM users
INNER JOIN posts
ON users.id = posts.author_id
WHERE posts.board_id = [desired board ID]
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: what does the `MIN` syntax do?

Comment: Because we are grouping by `users.id`, we should apply some aggregate to all the columns that are not in group by. MIN just selects the smallest value for the group, but in this case all the values in the group will be the same, so it will just select that value. MAX would result in the same output.

Comment: I guessed MIN was a numerical identifier but seemed a bit odd to use it on a name and url field which are strings (or at least, expected to be). How come you've used them at all?

Comment: MIN works on any type, that has order defined on it. Strings do, so MIN works with them. If your table has several strings in column `a`, `MIN(a)` will return the lexicographically smalleset of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, users.avatar_url, posts.author_id
FROM users
INNER JOIN posts
ON users.id = posts.author_id
WHERE posts.board_id = [desired board ID] GROUP BY users.id
```

This will get all found rows and then group them by the userid so each user id will appear just once, hence each user row [who posts on the board] will appear just once.

Comment: While this does work in MySQL, generally it is a bad idea to select anything which is not an aggregate or a column you group by on, if you have a group by.

Answer (score 0):

Yet better is use with annotation `not` for highlighted after `IN`, which defense against duplicate values. That's it.